# Create the new hash from the old one with Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have some simple_hash:

```
old_hash = {"New"=>"0"}
```

I wan to convert it to new format:

```
new_hash = old_hash.keys.each do |key|
  hash = Hash.new
  hash[key] = {count: old_hash[key]}
  hash
end
```

but this code returns me:

```
["New"]
```

instead of:

```
{"New"=>{:count=>"0"}}
```

And the question is why?

Comment: Where is `simple_hash`?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the syntax of block with that of a method. In your code, `new_hash` gets the value of `old_hash.keys`, which is not what you want.

A little modification works:

```
new_hash = Hash.new

old_hash.keys.each do |key|
  new_hash[key] = {count: old_hash[key]}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
hash = Hash.new
new_hash = old_hash.keys.each do |key|
 hash[key] = {count: old_hash[key]}
 hash
end

hash
# => {"New"=>{:count=>"0"}}
```

Since you placed `hash = Hash.new` inside the loop, you are creating a new hash every time.

Comment: What's up with `new_hash`?